# How is a proxy able to decrypt HTTPS traffic without the server certificates?

Tags: proxy, ssl-certificate, https

I'm working on a project that involves proxying traffic between some client applications and servers. For this I'm using [AnyProxy](https://anyproxy.io/en/).

My project requires decrypting HTTPS.
I'm able to this with AnyProxy, by having it [generate a rootCA](https://anyproxy.io/en/#proxy-https) and then trusting that rootCA on the client machine(s).

And it works, but I don't understand how/why it works from a theoretical point of view.

As far as I know, HTTPS encryption/decryption works like this:

1. The server generates a public key and a private key.
2. The server generates a certificate based on the keys.
3. It registers said certificate with a CA (certificate authority). This is so client applications (such as web browsers) can verify the authenticity of the certificate from a trusted source.
4. A client application makes an HTTPS request to the server.
5. During handshake, the client verifies the authenticity of the certificate (and thus, of the server) and receives the server's public key.
6. The client encrypts the request with the server's public key.
7. The server decrypts the request with its private key.

With the proxy comes into the picture, it would need the server's private key to decrypt the client's request.
How does it get it?
Can someone please explain what I'm missing (or, if I got it all wrong)?

Comment: I think numbers 6 and 7 are off/misleading. Technically, the server's public key is used by the client during the Key Exchange process, where a unique session key is generated and used to symmetrically encrypt data over that HTTPS session. Otherwise, how would the server securely send data back to the client? If using the server's private key the data could easily be decrypted by an eavesdropper, for example. During the handshake in step 5, a cipher suite is negotiated, let's say `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`, meaning the symmetric key is actually using AES256 (for this cipher suite).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly why you need the root CA generated and installed on the client: it enables your proxy to issue fake certificates for every domain. The proxy doesn't decrypt an existing connection between the client, but establishes two separate connections: it's acting as a client towards the server and as a server for the client. Roughly like this:

[image: HTTPS interception sequence diagram]